# Hangfire stop working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I am using hangfire version "1.6.12.0". It is working fine, but when error occurred it stop working on the scheduled job.

As i saw in log file error was:

> Message:Thread was being aborted.
>   stack:at System.Threading.Thread.SleepInternal(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
>      at System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
>      at HangfireCronJobs.Controllers.HomeController.Myfunction()

But when i hit the hangfire URL on browser then scheduled jobs are started automatically.

My code is as below:

```
 public ActionResult Recurring()
    {
                RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => JobExicute(), Cron.MinuteInterval(10));
    }
public void JobExicute()
{
            fun1();
            fun2();
            fun3();
}



 public static void fun1()
    {
        try
        {
            string strPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EXEpath"].ToString();
            Process p = new Process();

            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"" + strPath + "" + "\\map1.exe";
            p.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.Log("Error Message: " + ex.Message, 0);
            Logger.Log("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace, 0);
        }

    }
    public static void fun2()
    {
        try
        {
            string strPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EXEpath"].ToString();
            Process p = new Process();

            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"" + strPath + "" + "Graph\\map2.exe";
            p.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.Log("Error Message: " + ex.Message, 0);
            Logger.Log("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace, 0);
        }
    }
    public static void fun3()
    {
        try
        {
            string strPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EXEpath"].ToString();
            Process p = new Process();

            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"" + strPath + "" + "Graph\\map3.exe";
            p.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.Log("Error Message: " + ex.Message, 0);
            Logger.Log("Stack Trace: " + ex.StackTrace, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: How can we know if you have only this piece of message?

Comment: I got this error message by my log files. after this message log file is not update.

Comment: How to restart job when it stop working.

Comment: @RahmanyUsama, can you post the code which you define the hangfire job?

Comment: I have updated my code please see.